# Publish posts in facebook group wall via python

Tags: python, facebook

Need help with subject. I use facebook-sdk, and doing:

```
graph = GraphAPI(FB_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN)
graph.put_wall_post('message', {"name": "Link name", "link": "http://www.site.ru/", "caption": "posted a new review", "description": "This is a longer description of the attachment", "picture": "http://www.example.com/image.jpg"}, profile_id=FB_GROUP_ID)
```

But I don't see picture on a group wall. What I'm doing wrong? How to publish image with description and link on a group wall?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [fb 0.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fb/0.1.0)

It's pretty simple and straight-forward. Here's the way I use it: 
`import fb`
`token="app_access_token"`
`facebook=fb.graph.api(token)`
`facebook.publish(cat="feed", id="me", message="This is a status!")`

It works with almost any Facebook Graph API Parameter.
They have a list of instructions in their README.txt file.
Good luck! :)

Comment: OK, I've seen similar examples, but I need publish IMAGE to a GROUP wall. Specific parameters for publication in the group I do not know. or publications do not see the picture

Answer (score 0):

```
import facebook


group_id = 'group_id_here'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI('your_graphapi_here')

resp = graph.put_object(group_id, 'albums', name='photos')
photo = open('pic.png', 'rb')
caption = 'Cool'
message = 'Check this out'
graph.put_photo(photo, caption=caption, message=message, album_id=str(resp['id']))
photo.close()
```